# How to closw webView?

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiwebview, uibutton

I am designing a webView with a close button. When the application is launched, it opens the given url. When the button is touched, i want to close the webView.

I need some button event which closes the webView. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIWebView inherits from UIView. So the answer is: It depends!

If you're using a UINavigationController and used

```
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:newUIWebController];
```

you can close your UIView by using

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

If you're using some other method to display your view (like `addSubView`) you can utilize the corresponding method like `removeFromSuperview`.